# How can I add condition on mail notification laravel?

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-5, notifications, laravel-5.3

I use laravel 5.3

My notication laravel like this :

```
<?php
namespace App\Notifications;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\BroadcastMessage; 
class GuestRegistered extends Notification implements ShouldBroadcast, ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;
    private $data;
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->subject('test')
                    ->greeting('Hi')
                    ->line('Thanks')
                    ->line('Your password : '.$this->data)
                    ->action('Start Shopping', url('/'));
    }
}
```

I want to add condition in toMail method

So if `$this->data` not exist then `->line('Your password : '.$this->data)` not display or not executed

How can I do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add a default value for the `$data` parameter in the constructor .

```
public function __construct($data = null)
{
    $this->data = $data;
}
```

Then you can store the instance of `MailMessage` in a variable and use the `if` statement to add the `line()` you want.

```php
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    $mailMessage = new MailMessage();

    $mailMessage
        ->subject('test')
        ->greetings('Hi')
        ->line('Thanks');

    if($this->data) {
        $mailMessage->line('Your password: ' . $this->data);
    }   

    $mailMessage->action('Start Shopping', url('/'));

    return $mailMessage;
}
```