# Laravel Notification. Send Email if only Email address is avaiable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, notifications, laravel-queue

Currently, I am working with Laravel 5.7 Project

Now I am sending [Laravel Notification](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/notifications) (Email, SMS, and OneSignal Push)

User Email is optional(login with mobile).
Now, I want to send Email if only Email address is provided by user. Other wise I send SMS and Push notification will be sent always (with both Email and SMS).

In the Notification i check

```
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        if($this->user->email != null){
           return $(new MailMessage())->subject(__('Received Test Email  :app_name', ['app_name' => app_name()]))->view('mail.testView');
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Email is sending successfully if there is email address, but if there is no email address `return false` is executed and queue fails and it retries to send again. The queue never stop.

How do I not "Queue Email", if email address is not available?

Comment: first of all if($emailAvailable = 1) it should be if($emailAvailable == 1) other wise it's always true . second from where do you get $emailAvailable?

Comment: I have updated my code for StackOverflow, the actual logic have some data that can't be share, so the actual condition is somewhat this `if($this->user->email == 1) `. The condition I have put is correct, be assured of that. what I want to know is how to skip sending mail if the email address is not available.

Comment: Are you sure that `$this->user->email == 1` and not for example `$this->user->email == 'some@email.com'`?

Comment: Follow this link may be help you :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47742370/how-can-i-add-condition-on-mail-notification-laravel

Comment: Check "Cleaning Up After Failed Jobs" section on [Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#cleaning-up-after-failed-jobs) page.

Comment: I only want to send mail if an email address exists in user table if there is no email I don't want to queue email I have updated condition  @Tpojka, @ Manisha

Comment: there might be case that your mail list contain some value which has email format but not actual email that why it happen.

Answer (score 5):

You could also implement that check in the `via` method of your notification class and return `['mail']` only if the notifiable entity has an email address, otherwise return an array with the channels where you will notify your user or an empty array to skip the notification at all.

Answer (score 1):

Decouple that tightly coupled code. In place where you call `notify()` or `Notification::send()`, make check of email existence. There you should put `if` statement and check for email existence. Not in this sending method. Make that call only after you know email exists. And `toMail()` method should looks like

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage())->subject(__('Received Test Email  :app_name', ['app_name' => app_name()]))->view('mail.testView');
}
```

Nothing more. `toMail()` method shouldn't take care of checking email existence. 
It's name and should be function too is just to send email.

Comment: I disagree.  I would check mail existence in the “via” method.  Calling shouldn’t worry about that; caller just wants to ‘notify’ a user; the notification class is responsible for figuring out how and where to send it ;-)

Comment: @DavidHeremans Actually, you're quite right here. 
Feel free to write that answer and I will support it by voting up.